# Is it okay to leave circuit on when a bad GFI has tripped?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I have a very old GFI outlet in the kitchen that tripped. It apparently is connected to two other outlets, so all three have no power. Nothing is plugged into them now. I cannot reset the GFI, both the reset and the test button don't push in properly. I'm assuming the GFI is bad and needs replacing. The circuit breaker for this circuit has not tripped and there are some other outlets and lights on that circuit that I'd like to be able to remain working.

Is it okay to leave the circuit on until I can get somebody in to replace the GFI?

Comment: This is an easy DIY you can do by turning the breaker off and taking the old outlet out and install a new one. If the outlet is not hot it should be fine with power applied until it can be replaced.

Comment: @EdBeal you should make that write-up as the answer - maybe post a picture of the new GFC and wiring to the other outlets..for the op..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can leave the circuit on. The bad GFI just won't provide downstream power is all. There's no hazard there.
2. The GFI is bad and needs replacing. If you're OK turning the whole circuit off, you can use a screwdriver to replace this easily. The main thing you want to do is take note of which wires are on the LINE side (as in do this **before** you disconnect the old GFI). Mark them with tape and then disconnect the LINE side, and then the LOAD. When you hook the new GFI up, connect the LOAD and LINE just like they were in the old one. It's important you not mix them up. Beyond that, it's literally just unscrewing and screwing.